# sonata media bundle, can not preview an image

Tags: image, symfony, bundle, media, sonata

I dont know why but image preview is not working with my sonata admin bundle.

There is my config:

[image]

```
sonata_media:
    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr it is mandatory to choose one here
    default_context: default # you need to set a context
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

    cdn:
        server:
            path: "/uploads/media" # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media"
            create:     true

    providers:
        image:
            service:    sonata.media.provider.image
            resizer:    sonata.media.resizer.simple # sonata.media.resizer.square
            filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.local
            cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
            generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
            thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
            allowed_extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
            allowed_mime_types: ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']
```

and there what i get when i want to preview

[image: preview]

But the image is well upload so I dont get why its not displaying.

The directory where I upload: web/uploads/media

Answer (score 0):

Not the issue I was looking for, but quickly see what is wrong. Wrong path, see *reference* and *default_small*: ...default/default...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the img path should be wrong, and it suppose to be like,

```
filesystem:
     local:
         directory:  "%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads/media"
         create: false
```